# css doesn't work after importing it to scss file - angular 4

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have a CSS file, let's call it "**abc.css**". It is located in "**/src**" folder of the codebase along with "**styles.scss**". When I import this CSS file in "**styles.scss**" it works perfectly.

```
@import "abc.css"
```

I have created some component named "**xyz**". It also has a scss file named "**xyz.component.scss**". Now I want to import "**abc.css**" in "**xyz.component.scss**". So I do

```
@import "../../abc.css";
```

But the problem is that here the styles of "abc.css" doesn't get reflected on that component after firing "**ng serve**".

I am confused that how this css file is working when I import it in global "styles.scss" but not working inside the component. Can someone help me resolving this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Add `abc.css` in your `.angular-cli.json` file under the `styles` entry where `styles.scss` is also added. That should solve this problem.

Comment: @Faisal, I don't want this css to be used globally, I want this to use only in 2 components out of 10 components particularly.

Comment: I'm tried this on Angular 11 and still does not work. An alternative way is to config lazy file and loads it by yourself, ref: [How to lazy load global style?](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5880)

Answer (score 0):

You can import two style files (or more) in your component declaration:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `

  `,
  styleUrls: ['./xyz.component.scss','../../abc.css']
})
export class MyComponent{
/* . . . */
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's not helping me. Thanks anyway